# Count total expenses of last three months and average expenses per trip in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with customers' expenses by date. I want to have the last three months expense and avg. expense based on the list visit of each customer. How can I do that in R?

below is the dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

name <- c('Mary','Sue','Peter','Mary','Mary','John','Sue',
          'Peter','Peter','John','John','John','Mary','Mary',
          'John','Mary','Peter','Sue')
date <- c('01/04/2018','03/02/2017','01/01/2019','24/04/2017',
          '02/03/2019','31/05/2019','08/09/2019','17/12/2019',
          '02/08/2017','10/11/2017','30/12/2017','18/02/2018',
          '18/02/2018','18/10/2019','30/04/2019','18/09/2019',
          '17/11/2019','08/08/2019'
          )
expense <- c('300','450','550','980',
          '787','300','2343','233',
          '932','44','332','432',
          '786','345','567','290','345','876')

data <- data.frame(name,
                   date=lubridate::dmy(date),expense)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering 3 months as 90 days we can subtract 90 days from the `max` date for each `Name` and take mean of `expense` only for dates which fall within the range.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(last_3_month_expense = mean(expense[date > max(date) - 90], na.rm = TRUE), 
            mean_expense = mean(expense, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**data**

Read the expense data as numeric not as factor/character.

```
data$expense <- as.numeric(as.character(data$expense))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, I also want to ask how to count the days of last months group by names and mutate two additional columns to see 1. avg. expense per day and 2. assign a tier name based on the avg. expense. for example, if the expense per day is 100 i would put 0-100 and if its 200 and i put 200-300 and so on.

Comment: you can use `cut/findInterval`, something like `findInterval(mean(expense, na.rm = TRUE), seq(0, 1000, 100))`

Comment: but i am not looking for interval, i want to count the dates, for example john 3 times bcs he came for 3 days within last 3 months.

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question because it is difficult to understand what you want in comments. Further, extending question in comments invalidates current answers and confuses future readers.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 0):

We `arrange` by 'name', 'date', convert the 'expense' to `numeric`, calculate the `sum` of last 3 values of 'expense' and the `mean` of the 'expense' grouped by 'name' (assuming there is only data point per month)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   arrange(name, date) %>%
   mutate(expense = as.numeric(as.character(expense))) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>% 
   summarise(last_three = sum(tail(expense, 3), na.rm = TRUE), 
            average_expense = mean(expense, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun. What about if I also want an extra column to count total transaction days of last 3 months?